# What is a FORM's equivalent to DOM's getNextSibling?

Tags: javascript, forms, dom

I have a form, as follows:

```
<FORM name="form1">
    <TABLE onkeypress="focusNextFormElement(event)">
        <TR>
            <TD><INPUT name="SomeObscureName"></TD><TD>Some data</TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
            <TD><INPUT name="ThisName"><span>Here's some obscure text.</span></TD><TD>Some data</TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
            <TD><INPUT name="someNameIdontKnow"></TD><TD>Some data</TD>
        </TR>
    </TABLE>
</FORM>
```

Is there a better, more efficient way to write this function? (Of course, this is a simplified example)

```
function focusNextFormElement(ev){
    var el = ev.target;
    var f = el.form;
    var xx = f.elements.length - 1;
    for(var x = 0; x < xx; x++){
        if(f.elements[x] === el){
            f.elements[x+1].focus();
        }
    }
}
```

There may be thousands of elements on this form, and I don't see it as particularly efficient to loop through them all each time the function runs.

Also, I could arbitrarily select an input with my mouse, so a tracking array may not be of much use.

I have no control of the generation of the page, as it's a greasemonkey script to help with automation of another page.

**EDIT**
Thanks to @Trincot and, from a broader point of view, @Oriol, the answer is found.

```
function nextFormSibling(el){
    var elems = el.form.elements;
    var idx = [].indexOf.call(elems, el);
    return elems[idx+1] || el;
}

function previousFormSibling(el){
    var elems = el.form.elements;
    var idx = [].indexOf.call(elems, el);
    return elems[idx-1] || el;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get the element's index calling *indexOf()* on the form's elements collection. Although this collection is not a native JavaScript array, you can use *indexOf.call* like this:

```
function nextFormElement(el) {
    var f = el.form;
    if (f) return f.elements[1+[].indexOf.call(f.elements, el)];
}
```

Here is a demo snippet using this function to move focus to the next element when a form element is clicked. This is obviously quite useless, but it shows that it works:

```js
function nextFormElement(el) {
    var f = el.form;
    if (f) return f.elements[1+[].indexOf.call(f.elements, el)];
}

function focusNextFormElement(ev){
    var el = nextFormElement(ev.target);
    if (el) el.focus();
}

document.querySelector('form').onclick = focusNextFormElement;
```

```html
<FORM name="form1">
    <TABLE onkeypress="focusNextFormElement(event)">
        <TR>
            <TD><INPUT name="SomeObscureName"></TD><TD>Some data</TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
            <TD><INPUT name="ThisName"><span>Here's some obscure text.</span></TD><TD>Some data</TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
            <TD><INPUT name="someNameIdontKnow"></TD><TD>Some data</TD>
        </TR>
    </TABLE>
</FORM>
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically, no, without knowing the strusture of the DOM a priory, you need the index of the element in the `elements` collection in order to access the next one. And iterating it seems the only way, but consider using `indexOf` instead of doing it manually.

However, if you want to access the next element multiple times, you can do it only once and cache the result:

```
var nextFormElement = (function() {
  var cache = new WeakMap();
  return function(el) {
    if(!cache.has(el)) {
      var els = el.form.elements,
          idx = [].indexOf.call(els, el);
      cache.set(el, els[idx+1] || null);
    }
    return cache.get(el);
  };
})();
```

If ES6 is not supported you can use a plain object instead of a weakmap, where the values are the next elements, and the keys are some identifiers which you can store in the elements as `data-*` attributes.

Then, use it like

```
var next = nextFormElement(event.target);
if(next) next.focus();
```

```js
var nextFormElement = (function() {
  var cache = new WeakMap();
  return function(el) {
    if(!cache.has(el)) {
      var els = el.form.elements,
          idx = [].indexOf.call(els, el);
      cache.set(el, els[idx+1] || null);
    }
    return cache.get(el);
  };
})();
document.forms.form1.addEventListener('keypress', function(event) {
  var next = nextFormElement(event.target);
  if(next) next.focus();
});
```

```html
<form name="form1">
  <div>
    <input name="SomeObscureName" />
    <span>Some data</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input name="ThisName" />
    <span>Here's some obscure text.</span>
    <span>Some data</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input name="someNameIdontKnow" />
    <span>Some data</span>
  </div>
</form>
```

That said, this code is **completely obtrusive**, and I don't recommend it. If the user wants to focus the next text focusable field, he can use the tab key. If he doesn't want to change focus and you do it for him, it will be so annoying.

Comment: Your code encouraged me to learn a couple of things I didn't know: weekMap and indexOf.call. It so happens that the following works completely: return el.form.elements[[].indexOf.call(el.form.elements, el)+1]   I'm not sure thew weekMap will buy me much, since it's doubtful that I will select the same element twice per page, but I appreciate your having instigated me to learn about it. MANY THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the HTML strictily adeheres to your example you can try :

```
function focusNextFormElement (ev) {
  // First find the tr element of this input...
  var tr = ev.target.parentNode.parentNode; // find the tr node
  // Advance to the next table row ...
  tr = tr.nextElementSibling
  // Then focus the input element in that row...  
  tr.querySelector ('input').focus ();
```

}

Comment: Yes, traversing the DOM is one way to do it, but I'm looking to traverse form.elements.

Answer (score 0):

Could you elaborate as what are you planning to achieve? Do you want to keep shifting your Input Focus to Input Elements? If so, it's better you should use the 'tabindex' attribute.

Rer: http://www.wufoo.com/html5/attributes/27-tabindex.html

If not, then would like to know more about the problem.

Note: Your 'onkeypress' on 'TABLE' element has more problem because, for every key pressed in the input field, it immediately switches to next input field.

Comment: I'm looking for the fastest method to get the next FORM sibliing into a variable. element.nextSibling, but a FORM's element list, rather than an element's parentElement.